# Return type function in java

Tags: java

```
public class prime 
{
    public static boolean Isprime(int n)
    {
        boolean Isprime = true;
        for(int i=2;i<n;i++)
        {
            if(n%2==0)
            {
                Isprime = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        return Isprime;      
    }
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        System.out.println(Isprime(5));

    }
    
}
```

can we make a boolean return type function in this case without initializing the Isprime variable?

if i make an else statement with returning true (so that there will be no need to initialize the variable) i can do return Isprime after the for loop, but it's giving me an error because i didn't initialize the isprime variable

Comment: an else block won't work, because it doesn't guarantee your for loop will be executed

Comment: You can remove the `Isprime` variable completely, and instead `return false` directly from inside the loop, and have `return true` after the loop.

Comment: Just `return false` in the loop instead of setting a variable and breaking. And `return true` after the loop. No need for the variable at all.

Comment: This is not how you check for primality. This code will always return `true` for any odd values. Your loop variable `i` is never used inside the block. You probably wanted to do `if(n%i == 0)`

Answer (score -2):

public class prime
{
public static boolean Isprime(int n)
{
for(int i=2;i<n;i++)
{
if(n%2==0)
{
return false;

```
        }
    }
    return true;      
}
public static void main(String args[])
{
    System.out.println(Isprime(6));

}
```

}

Comment: Please look at your answer and think about whether it would help readers in its current state: Is the code readable? Are you trying to help readers understand what you did and why?

Comment: Please take some time to read about [how to write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). What changes did you make to the code? Why did you make those changes? How does the changes solve the OP's problems? And what *is* the problem with the OP's code?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).